# kaminari(0.13) and haml (3.1.4)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

How to solve kaminari problem with haml? I m using haml haml (3.1.4)
and kaminari 0.13.
my index file looks like:

```
%h1 Listing customers
=paginate(@customers)
%table.index-list
    %tr
        %th Name
.....
but  i m getting an error 
undefined local variable or method `prev_span_tag' 
for    #<Kaminari::Helpers::Paginator:0xa848978>

Extracted source (around line #10):



    7:     paginator:     the paginator that renders the pagination tags inside
    8: -%>
    9: <%= paginator.render do -%>
    10:   <nav class='pagination'>
    11:     <%= current_page > 1 ? prev_link_tag : prev_span_tag %>
    12:     <% each_page do |page| -%>
    13:       <% if page.current? -%>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I found this question : [Rails heroku help kaminari view error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5888995/rails-heroku-help-kaminari-view-error). So i'd delete (and backup if necessary) your current views and regenerate them again